# replace last word in specific line sed

Tags: bash, awk, replace, cpu-word

I have file like

```
abc dog      1.0
abc cat      2.4
abc elephant 1.2
```

and I want to replace last word from a line which contains 'elephant' with string which I know.
The result should be

```
abc dog      1.0
abc cat      2.4
abc elephant mystring
```

I have `sed '/.*elephant.*/s/%/%/' $file` but what should be instead of '%'?

EDIT:
odd example

```
abc dogdogdogdog      1.0
abc cat               2.4
abc elephant          1.2
```

and now try to change last line.

Comment: `sed 's/\(elephant\)\(.*$\)/\1 mystring/' input`

Comment: Welcome to SO, as mentioned in comments too, keep changing requirements should NOT happen for any question. Also always add 3 things in your post, 1- sample of Input, 2- sample of expected output and 3- efforts which you have put in order to solve your problem in CODE TAGS in your post, happy learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** To preserve spaces could you please try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/elephant[^0-9]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)
  sub("elephant","",val)
  $NF=val "my_string"
  val=""
}
1
'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following(if you are ok with `awk`).

```
awk '/elephant/{$NF="my_string"} 1' Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself try following.

```
awk '/elephant/{$NF="my_string"} 1' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

Comment: it's good, but if I have multiple spaces, awk deletes it. how to prevent awk from doing this?

Comment: @czaduu, in case you are ok with TAB in spaces then you could try my 2nd solution.

Comment: @czaduu, with your given example it is showing fine for me, can you please post sample in your post and let me know then?(with odd spaces one)

Comment: you can find example at the end of my question

Comment: @czaduu, could you please try my EDIT solution now and let me know then?/

Comment: that's nice! thanks! one more question - I added edit2.

Comment: @czaduu, that is all together a different question, it is NOT recommended to keep changing your question, please open a new question for it. Remove that from this question too, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

basic

```
sed '/elephant/ s/[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}$/mstring/' $file
```

if some space could be at the end

```
sed '/elephant/ s/[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]*$/mystring/' $file
```

Answer (score 0):

an alternative to do the substitution and preserve the space:

```
awk '/elephant/{sub(".{"length($NF)"}$","new")}7' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$ cat f
abc dog         1.0
abc cat         2.4
abc elephant    1.2

kent$ awk '/elephant/{sub(".{"length($NF)"}$","new")}7' f
abc dog         1.0
abc cat         2.4
abc elephant    new
```

Answer (score 0):

Robustly in any awk:

```
$ awk '$2=="elephant"{sub(/[^[:space:]]+$/,""); $0=$0 "mystring"} 1' file
abc dog      1.0
abc cat      2.4
abc elephant mystring
```

Note that unlike the other answers you have so far it will not fail when the target string (`elephant`) is part of some other string or appears in some other location than the 2nd field or contains any regexp metachars, or when the replacement string contains `&`, etc.